# How to resume WebRTC call when one TURN server goes down

Tags: javascript, webrtc, turn

I have multiple turn servers in my WebRTC config:

```
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: 'turn:turn.example.com',
      username: 'username',
      credential: 'pass'
    },
    {
      urls: 'turn:turn2.example.com',
      username: 'username',
      credential: 'pass'
    }
  ]
```

When I start WebRTC call and then bring down `turn.example.com` the communication freezes. WebRTC does not seem to automatically pick up new ICE candidate and resume the call.

Is there a way to resume/reestablish communication using second ICE server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use an ICE restart to gather fresh TURN candidates. To do an ICE restart, you need to perform another offer/answer exchange that changes the ICE username fragments and passwords. To trigger this, you can simply call:

```
pc.createOffer({iceRestart: true})
```

Comment: Thanks, I found more information here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Session_lifetime#ICE_restart. Seems like the only way to go atm.